# How to get the top X most common fields in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have this kind of table, for what users like to eat for lunch:

| Name | Food for lunch | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Eggs | ... |
| Jerry | Pancakes | ... |
| Tom | Eggs | ... |
| Tom | Eggs | ... |
| Jerry | Pancakes | ... |
| Jerry | Beans | ... |
| Jerry | Burger | ... |
| Jerry | Beans | ... |
| Jerry | Burger | ... |
| Jerry | Pizza | ... |

I need to get the top X (let's say 3) most eaten types of food per user. How can this be done in SQL? Tried to figure it out for a while with no success.

Example answer:

| Name | Food for lunch |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | Eggs |
| Jerry | Pancakes, Beans, Burger |

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select name, array_agg(food order by cnt desc)
from (select name, food, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by name, food
     ) nf
where seqnum <= 3
group by name;
```

Note:  This combines the values into an array, which I prefer over a string.  However, you can use `string_agg()` if you prefer.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c4771491eda9b67d8cfa3ac3c941b57) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks.
The query you provided returns more than top 3. Can you tell why?

Comment: @Moses . . . Because there was a typo in the query.  It defined `seqnum` but then didn't use it.  I fixed it and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, I used this in sqldf (sqlite) but should work for postgresql as well:

```
with cte as(
      
      select Name,Food,
      count(Food) as food_count
      from df 
      group by Name, Food
      ),
      
      cte_2 as(
      select 
      Name, 
      Food,
      dense_rank () over (partition by Name order by food_count desc) as ranking
      from cte
      )
      
      select
      Name,
      group_concat(Food, ',') AS Food_for_lunch
      
      from cte_2
      where ranking = 1
      group by Name
```

Explanations:

cte will group the table by Name and food and count the number of
every food in food column cte_2 will create a ranking based on the
number of food (asc)

finally, we use where clause to filter top food based on the ranking
above and use group_concat() to group the column based on food column
and flatten the rows into one column. I think postgresql use
string_agg() for this function.

The weakness of this method, because you have foods that have the same total count, they will get the same rank.